# Default value of a protected member c++

Tags: c++, initialization

### Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Example
{
public:
    int _public;

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, Example& o);

protected:
    int _protected;

private:
    int _private;
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, Example& o) {
    stream <<
    "_public=" << o._public << endl <<
    "_protected=" << o._protected << endl <<
    "_private=" << o._private << endl;
    return stream;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Example e;
    cout << e << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

> _public=4196960
>   _protected=0
>   _private=4196368

### Question:

All the three members are uninitialized. But only the `public` and `private` members have garbage values in them. Why is the `protected` member initialized to zero? Is there a reason for that?

---

### g++ version and flags

> g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
>
> -std=c++11

Comment: `return stream;` is missing in your code example in the `operator<<` function

Comment: @SaileshD Oops, yes. Thanks!

Comment: You are seeing the symptoms of undefined behavior. Explicitly initialize the member variables and you won't have to worry about strange values at all.

Comment: @RSahu Yes, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that reading [uninitialized variables](https://en.cppreference.com/book/uninitialized) is undefined behavior. 
You need to define a constructor for your class. 
And this has nothing to do with the access specifiers. It just happens (in your case) that the `protected` member is at an address which previously contained the value 0.

Also better not to use variable names starting with underscore. They are reserved.
It is allowed to use them in class scope but remember not to use them in global scope.

> 5.10 Identifiers [lex.name]
>
> 3  In addition, some identifiers are reserved for use by C++ implementations and shall not be used otherwise; no diagnostic is
>   required.
>   ...
>
> (3.2) Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to
>   the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with those identifiers at class scope. The standard reserves them at the global namespace only.

Comment: I just ran the above code in VS 2017 and got all values as `0`. Ran it several times, but the output hasn't changed. Is it compiler specific?

Comment: @P.W Yes, I've only used them for this example purpose, and inside the class scope.

Comment: @SaileshD: Compiler specific means implementation defined behavior. Reading uninitialized variables is not implementation defined but undefined behavior.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: @aschepler I was just going to comment that link :)